# LINQ to SQL Single Table Inhertiance

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am using LINQ to SQL with single table inheritance for an audit log.  There is a field/property called Type that i am using as the dicriminator and i have created a base type and a single inherited type (there will be more later if i can actually get this to work).

So that i don't have to write a different method to insert each different derived audit type the method takes the base type, but it doesn't work, it throws a `SQLTypeException` saying that the date is out of range, despite the fact that the only date field has been set using `DateTime.Now`.  I have written some basic debugging code and found a strange effect.  The below code works fine:

```
tOnHoldReasonAudit dbAudit = new tOnHoldReasonAudit();
dbAudit.ApplicationID = 1;
dbAudit.Date = DateTime.Now;
dbAudit.UserID = 9;
pi_DataContext.tApplicationAudits.InsertOnSubmit(dbAudit);
pi_DataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

However if i change the first line to

```
tApplicationAudit dbAudit = new tOnHoldReasonAudit();
```

where `tApplicationAudit` is the base type it throws the exception, specifically:

```
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.
```

Why does this not work, what exactly is going on here.  In my live code i have a method `AddAudit(tApplicationAudit Audit)` that does the actual work, i don't want to have to write an add method for each different derived type as this defeats the whole object, if i have to do that i might as well do away with the derived audit types and just set the type property on the base class.

Update:

Below is the initial part of the class definitions for the LinqTSql audit types that was created by O/R designer:

```
[Table(Name="dbo.tApplicationAudit")]
[InheritanceMapping(Code="1", Type=typeof(tOnHoldReasonAudit), IsDefault=true)]
public partial class tApplicationAudit : INotifyPropertyChanging,INotifyPropertyChanged

public partial class tOnHoldReasonAudit : tApplicationAudit
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the tApplicationAudit and tOnHoldReasonAudit classes?  It's hard to figure out what's wrong without seeing that code too.

Comment: The code was generated by the O/R designer and the full class definition is rather large.  I have updated the post with just the class definition and attributes.

Comment: Post the date property definition causing the error too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.  It was because the properties on the derived type were simply hiding the coresponding properties on the base type.  When i changed the properties on the base type to virtual and the override on the derived type, it fixed it. I think linq to sql must have been casting it back to the derived type to access the data.